# Problem doing a line integral $\int_C P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametrization, line-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_C P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy$$ where
> $P(x,y) =  y^2 $, $Q(x,y) = x$, and
> $C$ is the part of the graph $x = y^3$ from $(-1,-1)$ to $(1,1)$.

I was trying the parametrization:
$$x = t $$
$$y = \sqrt[3] t$$
$$dx = 1$$
$$dy = \frac{1}{3}t^{-2/3}$$
from which:
$$\int y^2dx+xdy=\int_{-1}^1 \left(t^{2/3}+ \frac{1}{3}t^{1/3}\right) dt= \frac{17}{10} $$
which is not the correct answer, correct answer is $\dfrac{6}{5}$.

Comment: Put $y=t$ and $x=t^3$ with range $-1 \le t \le 1$.

Comment: @Koushik_halder How do you know that?

Comment: Your parametrization is not wonderful, because it's not continuously differentiable. Nevertheless, your $17/10$ is wrong; if you do the integration and arithmetic correctly, you get the correct answer.

Comment: @TedShifrin how do you know is not continuosly differentiable

Comment: Look at $dy/dt$ on the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your non-smooth parametrization $(t,\sqrt[3] t)$ for $t\in[-1,1]$ (it is not differentiable at $t=0$):
$$\int_C y^2dx+xdy=\int_{-1}^1 \left(t^{2/3}+ \frac{1}{3}t^{1/3}\right) dt= 2\int_{0}^1 t^{2/3}\,dt=\frac{2}{2/3+1}=\frac{6}{5}$$
where we applied the fact that $t^{2/3}$ is an even function and $t^{1/3}$ is an odd one.

A smooth parametrization of $C$ is $(t^3,t)$ for $t\in[-1,1]$. Hence
$$\int_C y^2dx+xdy=\int_{-1}^1 \left(t^2\cdot 3t^2+ t\cdot 1\right) dt=
6\int_{0}^1 t^4\, dt=\frac{6}{4+1}=\frac{6}{5}$$
(note that $t^4$ is an even function and $t$ is an odd one).